# UEFI secure boot prevents Windows 10 from starting after a resizing operation

Tags: partitioning, uefi, secure-boot

I'm currently running "Windows 10" with "secure boot" ON and the OS is installed on a SSD drive.

I resized the partitions of another drive and the operations went well according to the application I used. Problem is, the motherboard now prevents Windows from starting unless I deactivate the "secure boot". I suppose it's because the size of the partitions have been altered.

Question: excluding a reinstall, is there a way to ask the motherboard to validate the changes I've made to that secondary drive in order to use that "secure boot"?

I've seen an option to delete (and backup) the keys that are used to secure the boot, but I'm not sure if it's going to help (and I fear I'm going to break something with that).

Comment: DO NOT delete the keys contained within Secure Boot.  Doing that WILL NOT solve your problem.  You have been warned.  Secure Boot does not care about the partition sizes.

Answer (score -1):

Try running the boot repair from Windows Recovery Environment. For this you need to create a Windows Boot Disk. There are detailed instructions on how to repair Windows Boot Entry on forums.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SuperUser. We are a Q and A kind of site, where all instructions should be in the answer. An answer stating: search on how to do it on the internet just is not a good answer and is likely to get you down votes.

Comment: Can I search on my own and post the link here? This problem is uncommon and the steps I outlined above are only a possible fix. That's why I refrained from giving a concrete advice.